# JavascriptException when using Actions class from selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to clickAndHold and moveByOffset using Actions class by Selenium.
But getting 
`org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`

Code:

```
actions
.clickAndHold(element)
.moveByOffset(xOffset, 0)
.build()
.perform();
```

Also, I'm getting the exception when using actions click

```
action.click(element).build().perform()
```

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML on the page? Is the browser being redirected to another page while Selenium is performed the actions?

Comment: It sounds like either element or xOffset is undefined

Comment: @GregBurghardt It is no navigating to a different page. It stays on the same page. I'm afraid I can't share the HTML. But it is simple click operation on an element in page. But it won't occur on every click. only specific element.

Comment: You do not need to share the full HTML of the page. Can you post a snippet of the relevant HTML --- just a small part of the page?

Comment: @GregBurghardt let me check with the devs and share if that is okay with them.

Comment: @pguardiario Element is present in the DOM. I have checked it

Comment: Also, I figure out an alternative to click. But unable to find a better alternative for moveByOffset

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm sorry, We are not allowed to post snippets of html atm. But I can tell you that our application uses kendo.

Comment: @Rameshwar: I understand that you cannot post code, but unfortunately we will not be able to help you. We need to see the HTML structure when dealing with selenium issues.

Comment: Maybe you can add an explicit "wait" as part of the action chain?

Comment: ty for your quick reply @GregBurghardt. I have added explicit wait before that